# How can i get image path with location name like from d or e or f or drive?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I want to get total path,for example if the user upload an image from d drive like:
 `D:/sample.jpg ,`

I want to get total that path only (*D:/sample.image*).

Is it possible ? if possible please help me(Java using servlet).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include some code. Also, tell us what EE server you are using and all this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not exposed to websites.

When a user uploads a file, only the path name component of the file can be thrusted. Google chrome for examples uploads files with `C:/fakeroot/image.png`. The only way for you to get the real path is either using a java or flash applet that upload the files manually.